# How to use UIImagePickerController from webview

Tags: javascript, ios, swift3, wkwebview

I'm following this tutorial online https://makeapppie.com/2016/06/28/how-to-use-uiimagepickercontroller-for-a-camera-and-photo-library-in-swift-3-0/ (with a little bit of a twist). I'm trying to call my `UIImagePickerController` from a webview and I'm not sure how to change the code to get it to work properly. The difference is that I'm going to be receiving a call from javascript and then invoking the picker as a result instead of with a UIButton. Then I want to send the image back as a base64 string using my javascript interface.

Here is what I have so far.

```
import UIKit
import WebKit

class ViewController: UIViewController,
                        WKScriptMessageHandler,
                        UIImagePickerControllerDelegate,
                        UINavigationControllerDelegate {


    var webView: WKWebView?
    let userContentController = WKUserContentController()
    let picker = UIImagePickerController();

    @IBAction func photoFromLibrary(_ sender: UIBarButtonItem) {
        picker.allowsEditing = false
        picker.sourceType = .photoLibrary
        picker.mediaTypes = UIImagePickerController.availableMediaTypes(for: .photoLibrary)!
        present(picker, animated: true, completion: nil)
    }


    override func loadView() {
        super.loadView()


        let config = WKWebViewConfiguration()
        config.userContentController = userContentController

        self.webView = WKWebView(frame: self.view.bounds, configuration: config)
        userContentController.add(self, name: "iOS")

        let url = URL(string:"https://relate.lavishweb.com/account")
        let request = URLRequest(url: url!)
        _ = webView?.load(request)

        self.view = self.webView



    }

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        picker.delegate = self
    }


    func userContentController(_ userContentController: WKUserContentController, didReceive message: WKScriptMessage) {

        webView?.evaluateJavaScript("window.settings.setImageBase64FromiOS()") { (result, error) in
            if error != nil {
                print("Success")
            } else {
                print("Failure")
            }
        }


        // now use the name and token as you see fit!
    }

    func imagePickerController(_ picker: UIImagePickerController,
                               didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo info: [String : AnyObject])
    {
        let chosenImage = info[UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage] as! UIImage //2
        //        myImageView.contentMode = .scaleAspectFit //3
        //        myImageView.image = chosenImage //4

        //I want to do additional stuff here and send back as a base64 String
        dismiss(animated:true, completion: nil) //5

    }
    func imagePickerControllerDidCancel(_ picker: UIImagePickerController) {
        dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay I figured it out,

So I didn't know what IBAction was but basically that means that the function that I'm going to declare after it is something that is called by an Interface Builder Element such as a UIButton or something like that. After realizing this, I just changed the function to

```
func photoFromLibrary() {
    picker.allowsEditing = false
    picker.sourceType = .photoLibrary
    picker.mediaTypes = UIImagePickerController.availableMediaTypes(for: .photoLibrary)!
    present(picker, animated: true, completion: nil)
}
```

then in my JavaScript interface I simply called the function when I received the call from JavasScript.

```
func userContentController(_ userContentController: WKUserContentController, didReceive message: WKScriptMessage) {

    webView?.evaluateJavaScript("window.settings.setImageBase64FromiOS()") { (result, error) in
        if error != nil {
            print("failure")
        } else {
            self.photoFromLibrary()
        }
    }
}
```

Stay tuned and I will post how to encode an image to a Base64 string while also shrinking it at load time.(Once I find out how to do that ofcourse)

EDIT: I figured out how to resize the image and convert to Base64 string very quickly.

I implemented this extension...

```
extension UIImage {
    func resized(withPercentage percentage: CGFloat) -> UIImage? {
        let canvasSize = CGSize(width: size.width * percentage, height: size.height * percentage)
        UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(canvasSize, false, scale)
        defer { UIGraphicsEndImageContext() }
        draw(in: CGRect(origin: .zero, size: canvasSize))
        return UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext()
    }
    func resized(toWidth width: CGFloat) -> UIImage? {
        let canvasSize = CGSize(width: width, height: CGFloat(ceil(width/size.width * size.height)))
        UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(canvasSize, false, scale)
        defer { UIGraphicsEndImageContext() }
        draw(in: CGRect(origin: .zero, size: canvasSize))
        return UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext()
    }
}
```

and then I returned the string like so...

```
func imagePickerController(_ picker: UIImagePickerController,
                           didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo info: [String : AnyObject])
{
    let chosenImage = info[UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage] as! UIImage 
    let thumb = chosenImage.resized(toWidth: 72.0)
    let imageData:NSData = UIImagePNGRepresentation(thumb!)! as NSData
    let dataImage = imageData.base64EncodedString(options: .lineLength64Characters)
    print(dataImage)
    dismiss(animated:true, completion: nil) //5

}
```

Answer (score 1):

Hi I have the same problem an ein solved it, but it's a little dirty.
In viewDidLoad() you override the Delegate from WKWebView. The WKWebView use the Delegate, too. You need to save the Delegate local.

```
var oldDelegate: UIImagePickerControllerDelegate?

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    oldDelegate = picker.delegate   // save the Delegate from WKWebView
    picker.delegate = self
}
```

now you you can run your code in your delegate. In the end of your method imagePickerController() you have to invoke imagePickerController() from the old delegate.

```
func imagePickerController(_ picker: UIImagePickerController,
                               didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo info: [String : AnyObject]){
        var myinfo = info
        let chosenImage = info[UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage] as! UIImage //2
        //        myImageView.contentMode = .scaleAspectFit //3
        //        myImageView.image = chosenImage //4
        myinfo[UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage] = chosenImage
        myinfo[UIImagePickerControllerImageURL] = nil

        oldDelegate?.imagePickerController!(picker, didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo: myinfo)
    }
```

I set the URL nil, because the WKWebView load the image direct from drive if the URL is filled.
myinfo[UIImagePickerControllerImageURL] = nil

I hope this is helpful.